# How to make a python decorator stop a user flow entering a function?

Tags: python

I currently have a authorization header:

```
def authorize(allowed_groups=None, debug=False):
    # Do your auth here...
    headers = cherrypy.request.headers
    return 
    if 'consumer_key' in headers:
        if check_consumer_key(headers['consumer_key']):
            if 'access_token' in headers:
                cherryPy.accept = check_access_token['access_token']
    else:
        cherrypy.accept = False
```

I'm using it here:

```
@cherrypy.tools.authorize()
def GET(self, id=None):
    #return the order list for this account type
    if cherrypy.accept:
        print "Accepted"
    user = User()
    usermodel = user.get_all()
    return json.dumps(usermodel, cls=AlchemyEncoder)
```

So, rather than doing a cherrpy.accept = True, how can I return an error page in the decorator itself when the authorization isn't right?

Answer (score 1):

You could just make another decorator that will only call the original function if the authorization succeeds and otherwise just displays an error page instead. This way you can avoid changing the other decorator.

```
def rejectNotAuthorized (f):
    def inner ():
         if cherrypy.accept:
             f()
         else:
             displayErrorPage()
    return inner

@cherrypy.tools.authorize()
@rejectNotAuthorized
def GET(self, id=None):
    pass
```

Of course you could also integrate that into the original decorator. You just need to make sure to return a function that, depending on the authentication result, either runs the real function or shows the error.

Comment: I've edited the decorator to return lambda:None but even still it doesn't stop there and enters the GET function.

Comment: Well, what you have shown for the `cherrypy.tools.authorize` in your question is not really a decorator (and it does not return one), so I have no idea how this is even supposed to work. I assume that you left code out?

Comment: How do I integrate the rejectauthorized function? I understand that cherrpy.tools.authorize isn't a decorator and more of a route dispatcher tool of Cherrypy.